# Refuse to execute script from JavaScript file because of MIME type

Tags: javascript, reactjs, mime-types, mime

I build a new react app and build and deploy it on goDaddy.com.
But it is not working on Safari in iOS & iPhone, but worked with Chrome.
When I config SSL settings and turn HTTPS redirects, and the site gives me This error.

[image: Errors from my console]

I searched all articles regarding this problem but they didn't work for me.

I already add this code line in the public/index.html

```js
   <base href="./" />
```

I already tried with `<base href="/" />`  but it didn't work for me too.
I'll appreciate any help.

Comment: What's the content type of those files in Chrome?  You can check in the Dev Tools, Network tab. Check for the Content-type in the header section of the request.

Comment: How are you including that file?

Comment: It is a js file. And the site still don't come up in Safari. Thank you